# Uninitialized Constant GooglePlaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am currently using the [google_places gem](https://github.com/marceldegraaf/google_places) to try to access the places API. I am using the following code to get results:

```
class PlacesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:search]
        @client = ::GooglePlaces::Client.new(Rails.application.secrets.places_api_key)
        @places = @client.spots_by_query(params[:search])
    end
  end
end
```

I am running into an error of `uninitialized constant GooglePlaces`, which is replaced with `PlacesController::GooglePlaces` if I don't scope out. I believe this is a scoping issue, but nothing that I have tried fixes the issue. I am following the directions in the repo's readme and assuming that I don't have to include the source in the lib directory of my site. I can use the gem correctly from the rails console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use this API in rails application you need to use google_places gem.

add in gem file and run bundle install and restart the server once

**gem 'google_places'**

**Next Create a project in google console and generate secret key .**

https://code.google.com/apis/console

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

**Finally restart the server**

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think to restart the server as I usually don't have to in development. That fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: after any changes in configuration file's we need to restart the server

Answer (score 0):

The docs said the API auth call should be:

```
@client = GooglePlaces::Client.new(Rails.application.secrets.places_api_key)
```